# What is the openlayer.js alternative of unloadinvisibletiles of leaflet.js

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using open layers with a tile server. I want to load maps while panning and destroy the loaded region when out of screen (Alternative to unloadinvisibletiles of leaflet.js)

How am i suppose to achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't Leaflet do this automatically? When I zoom in and out of a map, or drag it to the left and then right, the tiles that were previously loaded have to be retrieved from the server again. Edit: sorry, misread your question.

Comment: Leaflet does it if 'unloadinvisibletiles' attribute is set to true. I am looking for this same functionality with openlayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ol3 maintains a tile cache and will automatically expire unused tiles when the cache is full (that is if it contains more than [2048](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/dfb55fb6a59035eee51776aa5218d01d14beef90/src/ol/ol.js#L42) tiles).